# Getting Number of Day in Quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to get Which day of the quarter when you give a current date.

For Example if i give 01/25/2012 then the output should be 25. Since it is the 25th day of the quarter.

Similarly if i give 02/01/2012 it should give 32 as output.

I am able to get the first day of the quarter but not able to get which day it is in the quarter.

I did something like this:

```
 SELECT FirstDayOfQuarter  = CONVERT(DATE, dateadd(qq, datediff(qq,0, GETDATE()),0))
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find the first day of the quarter:

```
DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, @TestDate) ,0)
```

Then find the difference in days with your given date.

```
DECLARE @TestDate DATETIME;

SET @TestDate = 'January 25, 2012';

SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, @TestDate),0), @TestDate) + 1;
```

Comment: if i give todays date it is giving me 24 instead of 25

Comment: To those wondering at peter's comment, don't forget the '+ 1' at the end!

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there.

```
SELECT DateDiff(dd,CONVERT(DATE, 
       dateadd(qq, datediff(qq,0, GETDATE()),0)),getDate())+1
```

Comment: Great minds thing alike Jamie F, but I think you need a +1 added to the number of days

Answer (score 1):

Try This to get number of days in a CURRENT QUARTER;

```
Select datediff(dd, 
         dateadd(qq, 
           datediff(qq,0, getdate()),0), 
         dateadd(qq, 
           datediff(qq,0, getdate()) + 1,0))
```